# I need centered, unnumbered section titles

Tags: sectioning, xetex, numbering

Every business book I have seen have section and subsection titles centered and without numbers.   If you just browse business books on Amazon and look at the preview you will see what I mean.

Conditions:

- I am using KOMA stuff.  Months ago I had some tenacious problems that were solved with KOMA and that is a given.  That means no use of `titlesec` and most of the other packages that are sometimes mentioned
- I do not want to change all sections in the book from using `section` to `section*`  This has the effect of eliminating number from sections completely, and omitting them from the TOC.  I want all of the normal section behavior, just I don't want the number to appear.  My understanding is that the goal of LaTeX is remove formatting from the content.  These are regular sections, I just want the number eliminated from the output of the section header.
- I found one answer to eliminate numbers, but it left the period after the number.  Suggested solution need to eliminate the period as well.  I want the header to display exactly what I put in the section brackets.

Here is my sample for testing:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\centering}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\section{First Section}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\section{Second Section}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Need to eliminate the numbers from the section headers.

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`?

Comment: Well well well, that seems to do it.

Comment: It would be better to ask @egreg to post an answer rather than taking credit for it yourself! That way, the person who helped you gets the credit and points. That is, it isn't really fair to post an answer yourself which is essentially given to you in comments on the very question you are answering. [Note: It is a bit different if somebody gives you a nudge in the right direction but you do most of the work in coming up with a solution. But that doesn't seem to be the case here.]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate; let me look for it.

Comment: Of course egreg should post and answer and get credit -- that is why I put a prominent declaration that credit should be given to egreg at the top of my answer.  I waited to see if egreg would make an answer, and am ready to tag his as the official answer.   However, he seems uninclined, and with 333K reputation figured maybe this is not top of the priority queue.  Still ready to tag his, but in the mean time I thought it was helpful to give the example of exactly what happens to the readers.

Answer (score 0):

This answer provided by @egreg is to use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` so the complete test file is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\centering}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\section{First Section}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\section{Second Section}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\subsection{Subsection}
asdfasdfasdf
\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image: correct output]

Thank you very much